# facebook-flash-api getting username without PHP

Tags: flash, facebook

trying to get the name of the user in Flash (not FLEX) without the PHP. Currently I have the session, the uid. But from here could not move forward towards getting the name.

Would really appreciate if someone could help out.

```
var fbook:Facebook;
var api_key:String="xxxx";
var secret_key:String="xxxxx";

var fb_session:FacebookSessionUtil=new FacebookSessionUtil(api_key,secret_key,loaderInfo);
var passed_vars:Object;
var fbcall:FacebookCall;
fbook=fb_session.facebook;
passed_vars=root.loaderInfo.parameters;
var uid:Number=Number(passed_vars["fb_sig_user"]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

facebook-flash-api is pretty much a bitch, used python/django to get it on the server side and rendered it.